# Problem to define a parabola with two tangents

Tags: calculus, vectors, analytic-geometry, vector-analysis, conic-sections

I'm currently facing with the problem that I have to define a **parabola with only two tangents** in 2D-space. The clue for this task is, that I just know the x-positions ($x_1$ and $x_2$) as well as the two angles of the tangents ($\alpha_1$ and $\alpha_2$). The **y-positions of the points are unknown**. After the parabola is defined it will be moved up or down so that the curve encapsulates a specific area with the x-axis. The angles are given by tilt sensors at the given x-positions. The parabola will describe the condition of a floating body, so the y-positions will vary with trim and draught.
 The parabola should be of the form:

$\overline F = \left( \begin{matrix} cos & -sin \\ sin & cos \end{matrix}\right) \cdot \left( \begin{matrix} t \\ at^2 \end{matrix} \right) \ and \ maybe\ \ + \left( \begin{matrix} x \\ y \end{matrix}\right) $

Unfortunately, I have no idea how to solve this. Can anybody give me a hint or a solution? I would highly appreciate this. Tank's.

Best regards
Nicolas

Answer (score 2):

Visual hint:

[image]

If you know two tangents and the tangency points, you also know where a third point of the parabola lies and you can easily construct two other points on the parabola by exploiting a skew reference system.

Comment: Hey Jack, thanks for your answer. To clarify my question... The tangents are not realy known because I have no y-positions. So I just know the angle of the tangents for the given x values. It's a bit tricky but there must be a solution.

Comment: I think I misunderstood something. What do you mean by the x-position of a tangent, i.e. the x-position of a line? Additionally, do you know the orientation of the axis?